# Deploy Play! framework 2.2 standalone version on centos

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm developing a little play app, and I want now to deploy it on my remote server wich run CentOS.

I followed the instruction from documentation and Play! web pages, so I have installed Play! framework on my server and then I start my webapp using "play start -Dhttp=80".
The application start and it gives to me :

```
Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:80
```

But when i try to hit my public ip from my browser it doesn't give me anything.

Any hint on what I am doing wrong will be helpful.

Comment: Is the port allowed remote access? Does it work on the default port 9000?

Comment: I think it should be, but how do I check if iis allowed? And no, it doesn't work on 9000 either

Comment: Try this for starters: `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT` ; `/etc/init.d/iptables save`

Comment: Done, but unfortunatly it doesn't work. Couldn't be that the problem is somewhere else (even if I don't know where)?

Comment: Where is the server? Is there some other network policy in place that might be blocking that port?